# ctypes: How to hande structure which contains structure which contains structure which...?

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I have a simple API in C:

```
void init( t_main_struct* p_main_struct );
void calc( t_main_struct* p_main_struct, float* p_result );
```

which I use as:

```
t_main_struct my_main_struct;
float my_result[3];

init(&my_main_struct);
calc(&my_main_struct, my_result);
```

I'd like to wrapp the above API using Python `ctypes`.

Problem is, `t_main_struct` is very complex: contains other structures which contain other structures which contain other structures, etc.

On the Python side I don't really need to access any `my_main_struct` internals, it's a black box. I only need to know the `calc()` result stored in `my_result`.

Is it possible to somehow simplify `ctypes` implementation for the `main_struct`? Do I have to specify all the struct members, including sub-structs? Or I can just somehow pass enough memory without specifiying all the struct details?

Comment: As long as the fake structure object has sufficient size and sufficient alignment, it should work. But if you need to handle arrays of these objects, you need to know the exact size.

Comment: It is just a matter of passing a pointer around. Define the pointer in Python as an abstract, void type of object pointed to, get the pointer from C and pass it back to C. (Note: I don't know Pytrhon.)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I need to create that object first, than pass it's address into `init()`.

Comment: Why not have C create it?

Comment: If the python doesn't care about the contents of the structure, then the traditional approach is to just pass it in as a raw void*, and then your callback functions have to convert the raw pointer back. In C++ you can strengthen this model somewhat by passing round a base class pointer to define a family. In C I have seen people declare a child class instance at the start of their actual class and pass that around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing [[Python 3.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

If you don't care about the structure's definition, and since both function take pointers as arguments, (in *Python*) the only thing you need to do, is have a buffer large enough to hold it (you can use *void* pointers to reference the *struct* instance). 
Bear in mind that **if the structure (recursively) contains pointers to other structures, those need to be allocated as well** if referenced (but I guess that would have to happen in *init*).

*dll00.c*:

```c
#if defined(_WIN32)
#  define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define DLL00_EXPORT_API
#endif


typedef struct _ComplexStruct {
    float f0;
    int i0;
    // The other members
} ComplexStruct;


#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

DLL00_EXPORT_API void init(ComplexStruct *pStruct);
DLL00_EXPORT_API void calc(ComplexStruct *pStruct, float *pResult);

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif


DLL00_EXPORT_API void init(ComplexStruct *pStruct) {
    if (pStruct) {
        pStruct->f0 = -3.5;
        pStruct->i0 = 5;
    }
}


DLL00_EXPORT_API void calc(ComplexStruct *pStruct, float *pResult) {
    if ((pStruct) && (pResult)) {
        (*pResult) = pStruct->f0 * pStruct->i0;
    }
}
```

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import ctypes


DLL_NAME = "./dll00.dll"


def main():
    dll00 = ctypes.CDLL(DLL_NAME)

    init = dll00.init
    init.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
    init.restype = None

    calc = dll00.calc
    calc.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)]
    calc.restype = None

    buf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(512)  # Create a buffer large enough to hold the structure

    init(buf)
    res = ctypes.c_float()
    calc(buf, ctypes.byref(res))

    print("Result: {0:.3f}".format(res.value))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    main()
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q058233135]> sopr.bat
> *** Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ***
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2017\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64
> **********************************************************************
> ** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.9.16
> ** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
> **********************************************************************
> [vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code00.py
> dll00.c
>
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /DDLL dll00.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:dll00.dll
> dll00.c
>    Creating library dll00.lib and object dll00.exp
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code00.py
> dll00.c
> dll00.dll
> dll00.exp
> dll00.lib
> dll00.obj
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> Result: -17.500
>
> Done.
> ```